# Sequence $(a_n)$ for which $ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( 1- \dfrac{m}{a_n +m} \right ) =r.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve the following question . Let $r\in (0,1)$ and $m\in \mathrm{N}$. Then there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathrm{N}}$ in $\mathrm{N}$ such that $$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( 1- \dfrac{m}{a_n +m} \right ) =r.$$
Is it possible that $ (a_n)_{n\in \mathrm{N}}$ be chosen strictly increasing?

Comment: The answer should be a routine exercise in undergraduate analysis. What is the source and background/motivation of this question? Gerhard "Would Recommend Migrating This Post" Paseman, 2020.04.08.

Comment: @Gerhard I need to construct such a sequence for part of my research. I do know that I need to deal with induction on n. But I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simple transformations your claim is equivalent to 
the following:

For each $M\in \mathbb{N}$ and $s>0$ there is a strictly increasing sequence $(a_n)\in\mathbb{N}^\infty$, such that
$$ \sum \limits_{n>0} \log \left(  1+ \frac{m}{a_n}\right) ~=~ s.$$
This can be proved by inductive construction of such a sequence.
Define $s_0=0$, and for $N>0$ choose 
$$ a_N~:=~ \min \left\{ k\in \mathbb{N}: \log \left(  1+ \frac{m}{k}\right) < s-s_{N-1} \right\}~~~~(1)$$
Apparently, $a_N$ is well-defined because the set on the right hand side is not empty.
It follows that 
$$ s_N~:=~ \sum \limits_{n=1}^N \log \left(  1+ \frac{m}{a_n}\right) ~<~ s.$$
Because the sequence $(s_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ is monotonously increasing and dominated by $s$, it converges to a limit $s^*\leq s$.
It remains to show that $s^*=s$.

Assume $\epsilon=s-s^*>0$.
Choose $N$ such that for all $M>N$ 
 $$\log \left(  1+ \frac{m}{a_M}\right)~<~ \epsilon$$
Apparently, the sequence $(a_n)_{n>N}$ is not a sequence of consecutive integers, otherwise $(s_n)$  would diverge, like the harmonic series.
So there are two consecutive members $a_M$ and $a_{M+1}$ with $a_{M+1}-a_M\geq 2$. Now one can consider the sequence 
where $a_{M+1}$ is replaced by $a_{M+1}-1$. 
Apparently  this sequence   is also a strictly increasing sequence with a larger limit value than $s^*$, but still smaller than $s$.
But this contradicts minimality of $a_{M+1}$  in condition (1) of the construction.

Answer (score 0):

Induction is not needed here.

Choose e.g. $a_n=cn^2$ for a real $c>0$ and then rewrite your equation as 
$$f(c):=f_m(c):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\Big(1-\frac m{m+cn^2}\Big)=\ln r.$$

Next, $f(c)<\ln(1-\frac m{m+c^2})\to-\infty$ as $c\downarrow0$, whence $f(0+)=-\infty$. Also, by the dominated convergence theorem (DCT), $f(\infty-)=0$. Also, again by the DCT, the function $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$. So, $f$ takes all values in $(-\infty,0)$, including the value $\ln r$. That is, $f(c_r)=\ln r$ for some $c_r\in(0,\infty)$.

So, the sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n=c_r n^2$ for all $n$ is a desired increasing sequence.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your consideration. Second, as it is mentioned in the statement of the question, a_n is supposed to be in N for all n\in N.
But it is not obvious that c_r can be chosen in N.
How could you guarantee it?